# How to use vuex map helpers in composition api in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

I spent a lot of time figuring out how to use vuex map helper function and finally, I didn't figure it out.

Now I have something like this:

```
setup (_, { root: { $store } }) {
    onMounted(() => {
      $store.commit('app/setApplicationWidth', innerWidth)
      console.log($store.getters['app/getApplicationWidth'])
    })
  }
```

So how I can use mapGetters, and mapMutations in composition API?

My vuex store looks like this:
/store/app.ts

```
import { GetterTree, MutationTree, ActionTree } from 'vuex'

export const state = () => ({
  appWidth: <Number> 0
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof state>

export const mutations: MutationTree<RootState> = {
  setApplicationWidth (state: any, payload: Number) {
    state.appWidth = payload
  }
}

export const getters: GetterTree<RootState, RootState> = {
  getApplicationWidth (state: any): Number {
    return state.appWidth
  }
}

export const actions: ActionTree<RootState, RootState> = {}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is `vuex-composition-helpers` [here](https://github.com/greenpress/vuex-composition-helpers). It seems to work from my cursory examination. However, there are some hiccups that you might want to pay attention to so you get off on the right foot:

1. You need to transpile it by adding to `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
  build: {
...
    transpile: ['vuex-composition-helpers']
  }
```

Otherwise you'll get an inscrutable "unknown keyword `export`" error.

2. Nested stores use the alternate `*Namespaced*` methods:

```js
import { useNamespacedGetters } from 'vuex-composition-helpers'

export default defineComponent({
...
  setup(_props, context) {
    const { articles, articlesInfo } = useNamespacedGetters('articles', [
      'articles',
      'articlesInfo',
    ])
```

All in all it's just a little better than the "raw" method of using `computed` on the store directly:

```js
import { computed } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
...
    const articles2 = computed(
      () => context.root.$store.getters['articles/articles']
    )
```